# How to check if element is null or empty in a field constructor?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Similar to `hasErrors`

```
<div class="form-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">

    @** this does not work **@
    @if(!elements.label.isEmpty && elements.label != null)
        <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    }

    @elements.input

    @** this does not work **@
    @if(!elements.infos.isEmpty && elements.infos != null) {
      <p class="help-inline">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</p>
    }

    @if(elements.hasErrors) {
        <p class="help-inline">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</p>
    }
</div>
```

Even checking for an empty string would be fine. I can't figure out how to do either.

In the view:

```
@inputText(
    loginForm("member"),
    'placeholder -> "email or username",
    '_help -> "",
    '_label -> null,
    'class -> "form-control"
)
```

I am using Play Framework 2.2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to flip your logic around. You always check for `null` first, otherwise you're potentially trying to call a method on a `null`.

Second, it would help if you included the actual error you are getting when you post a question here. Don't just say it "throws errors".

From my quick test it looked like it was complaining about the `isEmpty` method not existing for Scala's `Any` class. It does, however, have a `toString` which you can call first to get what you want.

```
@if(elements.label != null && !elements.label.toString.isEmpty) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `.toString` is what I was looking for. I thought label was a string already. I am having a hard time finding references for all this, do you know where I might be able to find some?

Comment: @mawburn I tend to look through Play's source code on [GitHub](http://github.com/playframework/playframework) and [scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current) for the Scala API stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake in your boolean logic. Your title says "null or empty" but your code says "not(empty) or not(null)".

You probably want to use "and" instead of "or", i.e.

```
@if(elements.label != null && !elements.label.isEmpty) {
  <label>...</label>
}
```

Comment: You're right. I just typed that in there for this question. That's not the issue though, because these checks do not work when used by themselves and throw errors. I got as far as knowing this can't be done the way I'm trying to do it (and that Scala doesn't like null), but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Not knowing what actual errors you're getting, I'll assume that it's because you check `element.label.isEmpty` before `element.label != null`; this leaves you open to the possibility of calling `null.isEmpty`, which should of course throw a `NullPointerException`